# Python text file search and update

Tags: python, file, search

I am trying filter items already searched out of an existing item list. My current code is below; no matter what is in 'last search items.txt' it does not seem to filter any items out.

```
def filter_recent_items(items):
#Clarify item results - only return if it wasn't run in the last search. 
#Clears & rewrites items to .txt file after each search
    newitems = []
    with open('last search items.txt', 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.read().split('\n')
        print lines
        for item in items:
            if item['id'] in lines:
                pass
            else:
                newitems.append(item)                          
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        for item in items:
            f.write("%s \n" % item['id'])            
    return newitems
```

The function input, items, is a list of dicts (each item has a set of keys):

```
items = [{'count': 1, 'postage': '0.0', 'listing type': 'StoreInventory', 'title': 'APPLE IPAD AIR 2 WITH RETINA DISPLAY 128GB SPACE GREY UNLOCKED 4G/WIFI', 'price': '828.89', 'start time': '2015-12-19T12:01:19.000Z', 'end time': '2016-01-18T12:06:19.000Z', 'item url': 'http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/APPLE-IPAD-AIR-2-RETINA-DISPLAY-128GB-SPACE-GREY-UNLOCKED-4G-WIFI-/151921257466', 'category': 'iPads, Tablets & eReaders', 'id': '151921257466', 'condition': '3000'},

{'count': 2, 'postage': '13.4', 'listing type': 'FixedPrice', 'title': 'Samsung SM-P350NZAAXSA Galaxy Tab A 8.0 w/S Pen WiFi 16GB NEW', 'price': '340.0', 'start time': '2015-12-19T11:56:51.000Z', 'end time': '2015-12-29T11:56:51.000Z', 'item url': 'http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Samsung-SM-P350NZAAXSA-Galaxy-Tab-8-0-w-S-Pen-WiFi-16GB-NEW-/252218618062', 'category': 'iPads, Tablets & eReaders', 'id': '252218618062', 'condition': '1000'}]
```

last search items.txt will contain, after this function has been run, a list of itemids, e.g.:

```
151921257466 
252218618062 
201487509183 
291642436891 
272081891024
```

The function should open 'last search items.txt', which should contain a list of item ids (from previous search). For each item in the function input it will look to see if 'itemid' is already in the text file. If not, it appends the item dict to the function output. Once this has been done it clears the text file and rewrites in the item ids from 'items', ready for the next time this function is called.

My issue is it doesn't find 'itemid' in the text file, even if it is actually in there (doesn't throw up any error messages, just appends the entire contents of 'items' to output). It was working fine when editing and testing on windows. I've since uploaded it to a unix VPS where it wasn't working, edited it slightly, and now it seems to work on neither windows or unix!

A second question would be, is there a more elegant way I can filter an item list (of dicts) to only return results that weren't in the list last time the script was run?

Comment: Can you give a) the specific traceback you're getting on the error, and b) an example of what might be found in the contents of `'last search items.txt'`.

Comment: I have edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line where you write the IDs from the current search into the file. By putting a space between the placeholder and the newline, that space gets written into the text file (i.e. the first line of the text file would be, say, '151921257466 '), meaning that when the contents of the text file are read out, that space is present in the items you're comparing the IDs of the current search to--which means that it does not match the IDs of the current search, regardless whether it should or not (because what you're comparing to has an extra space in it that will make it not match). Change `f.write("%s \n" % item['id'])` to `f.write(item['id'] + "\n")` should make it work on Windows--I don't have a Unix OS available to test it on, so if that doesn't make it work on Unix, I am unfortunately unable to assist.

Comment: I've edited the post to make it slightly clearer, the input 'items' is actually a list of dicts (each item is a dict) so item['id'] should, and does, return correctly - it just doesn't find it in 'lines'